# AMD GPU Compute with c++

Tags: c++, gpu, gpgpu, amd-rocm, hip

I'm new to the GPU compute world, and I'm trying to run some demo code on my AMD Radeon rx 7800xt GPU using ROCm 5.7 / HIP.
I've looked trough some sources, but I don't seem to find any answers on why the provided code doesn't work. I've been following [this tutorial](https://olcf.ornl.gov/wp-content/uploads/intro_to_hip.pdf) with [this repo](https://github.com/olcf/intro_to_hip/blob/master/examples/vector_addition/vector_addition.cpp).
The first problem was that I needed to insert `#define __HIP_PLATFORM_AMD__` at the begginig of the file. Why does the tutorial not mention this?
But the major problem is that in the line `int id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;` the compiler gives these errors:

```
GPUCompute\main.cpp line 16 error: use of undeclared identifier 'blockDim'
GPUCompute\main.cpp line 16 error: use of undeclared identifier 'blockIdx'
GPUCompute\main.cpp line 16 error: use of undeclared identifier 'threadIdx'
GPUCompute\main.cpp line 56 error: use of undeclared identifier 'hipLaunchKernelGGL'
```

*Note that I shortened the path for privacy reasons.*
What should I do? Do I need to declare them? If yes, how do I know what value to set them?

My code is:

```cpp
#define __HIP_PLATFORM_AMD__

#include <hip/hip_runtime.h>
#include <hip/amd_detail/amd_hip_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

// Size of array
#define N 1048576

using namespace std;

// Kernel
__global__ void vector_addition(double *a, double *b, double *c)
{
    int id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(id < N) c[id] = a[id] + b[id];
}

// Main program
int main()
{
    // Number of bytes to allocate for N doubles
    size_t bytes = N*sizeof(double);

    // Allocate memory for arrays A, B, and C on host
    double *A = (double*)malloc(bytes);
    double *B = (double*)malloc(bytes);
    double *C = (double*)malloc(bytes);

    // Allocate memory for arrays d_A, d_B, and d_C on device
    double *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    hipMalloc(&d_A, bytes);
    hipMalloc(&d_B, bytes);
    hipMalloc(&d_C, bytes);

    // Fill host arrays A, B, and C
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = 1.0;
        B[i] = 2.0;
        C[i] = 0.0;
    }

    // Copy data from host arrays A and B to device arrays d_A and d_B
    hipMemcpy(d_A, A, bytes, hipMemcpyHostToDevice);
    hipMemcpy(d_B, B, bytes, hipMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Set execution configuration parameters
    //      thr_per_blk: number of HIP threads per grid block
    //      blk_in_grid: number of blocks in grid
    int thr_per_blk = 128;
    int blk_in_grid = ceil( float(N) / thr_per_blk );

    // Launch kernel
    hipLaunchKernelGGL(vector_addition, blk_in_grid, thr_per_blk , 0, 0, d_A, d_B, d_C);

    // Copy data from device array d_C to host array C
    hipMemcpy(C, d_C, bytes, hipMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Verify results
    double tolerance = 1.0e-14;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if( fabs(C[i] - 3.0) > tolerance )
        {
            printf("Error: value of C[%d] = %f instead of 3.0\n", i, C[i]);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // Free CPU memory
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);

    // Free GPU memory
    hipFree(d_A);
    hipFree(d_B);
    hipFree(d_C);

    printf("\n---------------------------\n");
    printf("__SUCCESS__\n");
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("N                 = %d\n", N);
    printf("Threads Per Block = %d\n", thr_per_blk);
    printf("Blocks In Grid    = %d\n", blk_in_grid);
    printf("---------------------------\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I'm coding in Code::Blocks and (I think) I set up the compiler found in the directory of ROCm. I set the search directories for both the linker and the compiler.

My specs (if one would care) are:
CPU: Ryzen 7 7700X
GPU: Radeon RX 7800 XT w/ 16GB VRAM
RAM: 32GB
OS: Windows 11

*And for those who are interested in the desired behavior: I just simply want it to compile and preform the vector additions on my GPU.*

Comment: Hi, please provide more information, the code itself, and the actual problem/error... these speeds up problem solving.

Comment: Hi @YoushaAleayoub, my code is the exact copy of the one I linked except for the first line I mentioned.

Comment: these errors show up when you aren't including `hip/hip_runtime_api.h` but I am  seeing that you do include it in the first #include statement. Therefore, this must be happening because you are compiling with gcc??? If so, they you can't compile with gcc, you need to compile with `hipcc`

Comment: in hip repository there are a lot of examples, you can run `make` with `strace` and extract all the invocations to `clang` it is doing, so you will get all the flags that are required for successful compilation, in case you want to do it by hand (without make)